# How can i take specific Months out from a Column in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that has a column 'mon/yr' that has month and year stored in this format Jun/19 , Jan/22,etc.

I want to Extract only these from that column - ['Jul/19','Oct/19','Jan/20','Apr/20','Jul/20','Oct/20','Jan/21','Apr/21','Jul/21','Oct/21','Jan/22']
and put them into a variable called 'dates' so that I can use it for plotting

My code which does not work -

dates = df["mon/yr"] == ['Jul/19','Oct/19','Jan/20','Apr/20','Jul/20','Oct/20','Jan/21','Apr/21','Jul/21','Oct/21','Jan/22']

This is a python code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what do you want ?just filters single  column or filtered rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `dates` list, if we wanted to extract just 'Jul/20' and 'Oct/20' we can do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['Jul/19','Oct/19','Jan/20','Apr/20','Jul/20','Oct/20','Jan/21','Apr/21','Jul/21','Oct/21','Jan/22'], columns = ['dates'])

mydates = ['Jul/20','Oct/20']

df.loc[df['dates'].isin(mydates)]
```

which produces:

```
    dates
4  Jul/20
5  Oct/20
```

So, for your actual use case, assuming that `df` is a pandas dataframe, and `mon/yr` is the name of the column, you can do:

```
dates = df.loc[df['mon/yr'].isin(['Jul/19','Oct/19','Jan/20','Apr/20','Jul/20','Oct/20','Jan/21','Apr/21','Jul/21','Oct/21','Jan/22'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how to filter rows

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].isin(some_values)]
```

Comment: you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values